# Using semaphore to put particular threads in queue

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I am facing a problem where i have to deal with many threads which are trying to write a List of Strings in database. To make things clear lets consider 3 threads which are accessing the connection object to DB. All the threads will be having String. Lets sat Thread A has a string called "First", Thread B has "Second", Thread C has "First". Assume below is the critical part of code which i want to protect in a manner i will be explaining shortly.

```
writeToDataBase(String stringFromEachThread);
```

This method can be executed by Thread A and Thread B at the same time since they have different string values within them. I have to protect the above code while Thread A is executing from Thread C because Thread C is also having the same string value as Thread A. I need to make Thread C wait until thread A finishes the execution. So i came across java.util.Concurrent.Semaphore class which puts threads in queue. But in my case only the Thread C has to be put into a queue not Thread B. Because Thread B has a unique string value so it can be executed in parallel with thread A. Semaphore is blocking thread C while execution of thread A but it blocks thread B as well.Below is the code snippet where i am using semaphore to achieve this which has not been helpful upto now. I have been at this problem for over a week. Any suggestions to overcome this is deeply appreciated.

```
Semaphore sm = new Semaphore(1, true);
```

...
...

```
public void lock(String str) throws InterruptedException {
        if(!strAlreadExists()){
            return;
        }else{
            sm.acquire();
        }
}
```

Comment: I would consider using [synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) before I decided I absolutely need semaphores.  Here's good tutorial on "concurrency", the options you have, and the tradeoffs between those options:  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html

Comment: And how many strings are that? Also, even if you execute them concurrently, the database will serialize accesses. So why worry?

Comment: *"database will serialize accesses"*--not always, it will depend on isolation mode.

Comment: in your code method `strAlreadExists()` is very likely not atomic, and `if--else` is not atomic, thus the whole `lock()` method is not synchronized, so semaphore won't help. Take a look at `synchronized` or `java.util.concurrent.Lock`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou He wasn't talking about the `serializable` isolation mode. If all the writes go to the same table, they can't be written at the same time reliably regardless of isolation modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be asking for is to have *separate locks* for separate strings. Your code snippet seems to indicate that you think you can use one lock (whether it's a semaphore or other locking mechanism) but somehow not have it shared between unrelated threads. And that won't work.

One way to achieve a separate lock for separate strings is to have a map from string to lock. Here is an illustration with a simple lock, not a semaphore:

Declare a private map field:

```
private final ConcurrentMap<String, Object> lockMap = new ConcurrentMap<>();
```

Create a method for retrieving a specific lock for a given string:

```
private Object getLock( String str ) {

    Object candidateLock = new Object();
    Object returnedLock = lockMap.putIfAbsent( str, candidateLock );
    return returnedLock == null ? candidateLock : returnedLock;

}
```

For any string, this will first create a candidate lock, and try to put that in the concurrent map.

When any thread tries to put the candidate in the map, there will either already be a lock for this string in the map, or the candidate lock becomes the new lock for this string. Using `putIfAbsent(...)` ensures that all threads that come with the same string get the same lock object. If there was a lock in the map, the candidate will be thrown away for garbage collection.

Now, to access your critical code, you can do:

```
Object lock = getLock(str);

synchronized ( lock ) {
    writeToDataBase(str);
}
```

If you insist on using semaphores, you can use `new Semaphore(...)` instead of `new Object()` and use `acquire` instead of synchronizing. But the point is still that you get a separate lock/semaphore for each different string.

The downside is that the map can grow very large if you have a lot of strings and few repetitions. It's hard to delete anything from this map, unless you plan a separate mechanism that locks away *all threads* that access the map, once in a while, and clean up old strings. This is especially true if you use semaphores as usually there is a limited number of semaphores allowed by the operating system.

Comment: thank you so much. You exactly pointed out my mistake. I was indeed trying to use the same lock for unrelated threads. I mentioned earlier each thread is having a string but actually it is a List of strings. So if any of the string in the list is a duplicate of a string which is present in the other thread's list i have to put that in the queue as well. 
I don't insist on solving the problem using semaphores. is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @Parasuraman No, that's a completely different situation. If that is what you need, you should change your question to reflect your real problem and not a simplified problem that is not real. I suggest also showing what's inside the `writeToDatabase` that requires protecting, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a [Striped Executor Service](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue206.html) would be a good fit.

> This magical thread pool would ensure that all Runnables with the same stripeClass would be executed in the order they were submitted, but StripedRunners with different stripedClasses could still execute independently. He wanted to use a relatively small thread pool to service a large number of Java NIO clients, but in such a way that the runnables would still be executed in-order.

You could use your `String` as the key class so every database write using the asme string retains iit's order while all others can run in parallel.